# How to get Gnome Shell to remember my display preferences?

Tags: gnome, 14.04, multiple-monitors, gdm

I have a laptop. When I'm using just the laptop, I want to use the display (well, yeah, obviously) but when I plug in my monitor, I want to just use that monitor, not both screens.

Every time I boot up I have to go to Displays, turn off the laptop's, confirm that yes, the display is what I want to keep, close the Displays config. It works, but it hardly adds to productivity.

I'm using Gnome Shell under 14.04 LTS "Ubuntu Gnome". I was previously using 12.04 LTS stock Ubuntu + Gnome Shell, and the previous config seemed more intelligent in this regard. I note that the stock ubuntu + Gnome Shell  used lightdm and the Gnome remix uses gdm. I suspect that's a fix - don't use gdm - but it seems a shame because lightdm will load up a whole load of libs that I don't need/want, according to dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

On my laptop, I use key combination: <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, this is faster than going to parameters... 
I press this key combination about three successive times to get your desired configuration.